# After slicing an object from array of objects, when the sliced object will be destroyed and removed from the memory?

Tags: javascript

Lets, understand with an example -

```
var arr = [{Property1: "obj1"}, {Property1: "obj2"}]

var mappedReference = arr[0];

arr.splice(0, 1);  //Removing first object from the array

console.log(arr[0]);
console.log(mappedReference);
```

### Console log:

[image]

Why the variable mappedReference still holding the references and how will get destroy?

Comment: It will be returned from the `splice` call. `var removed = arr.splice(0, 1)`

Comment: Also, once you assign `var mappedReference = arr[0]`, nothing you do to the array affects the object at the first index. You could `delete arr[0]`, `arr[0] = null` or `arr.splice(0, 1)`. The object can't be garbage collected because of the variable.

Comment: @adiga, yeah objects not getting removed from the memory because someone still holding the references, that is also I'm thinking .

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the same object reference to the array and take the index later.

```js
var arr = [{Property1: "obj1"}, {Property1: "obj2"}]

var mappedReference = arr; // the complete array as object reference

arr.splice(0, 1);

console.log(arr[0]);
console.log(mappedReference[0]); // apply index here
```

Comment: Yeah, that's right, but my requirement is not hold the entire array but specific object references and when the slicing happens the variable's reference get updated to null. Is the object not destroyed because of that object's references still holding by someone ?

Comment: as long as a variable points to some content, the content remains.